# upgraded Magento 1.9.3.0 from 1.9.2.3 admin Images not showing & search broken

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade, image, search, ce-1.9.3.0

I recently upgraded to Magento ver. 1.9.3.0 from  1.9.2.3 everything seemed to go ok. Except after I clicked on the Refresh button, I got an Internal Server Error. So I fixed permissions via SSH to -

```
find . -type f \-exec chmod 644 {} \;
find . -type d \-exec chmod 755 {} \;
find ./media -type d \-exec chmod 775 {} \;
find ./var -type d \-exec chmod 775 {} \;
find ./media -type f \-exec chmod 664 {} \;
find ./var -type f \-exec chmod 664 {} \;
chmod 640 ./app/etc/*.xml
chmod 550 mage
```

The web site came back and both the front and back end seemed to be working fine. But I then noticed that search on the front end wasn't working. It says - "Your search returns no results" no matter what I search for. And in the admin side if I click -> Catalog -> Manage Products -> If I click on a product I get a page with an error that says -

```
Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'XML_NODE_PRODUCT_MAX_DIMENSION' in
 /home/myserver/public_html/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/helper/gallery.phtml
 on line 111
```

So I saw the file mentioned was gallery.phtml so I uploaded the older file from my backup and the older file allows the page to display correctly but when I click on Images on the left the page shows but without the images. The images show on the front end fine. I even tried to re-upload the images but that didn't help either. I downloaded the 1.9.3 package and put in a good current file and I got the same original problem I had after the upgrade.

So I have 2 issues that I know of -

1. I can't search on the front end. Update - Advanced Search works normal. Update - I found I had an extension installed called - Catalog Search Refinement I uninstalled it and the search is working!
2. The image won't display with the old `gallery.phtml` installed and with the current `gallery.phtml` installed I get the error above. Update - I was looking at the file `gallery.phtml` and saw the call for `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image::XML_NODE_PRODUCT_MAX_DIMENSION` I found a file named - `Image.php` in `app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Helper` I think this file was being referenced instead of the one in `app/code/Mage/Catalog/Helper` So I copied the file over and now the page works and displays the images. I went a step further and renamed the file to .bak so that the correct file would be called and the page is working and the front end seems to be ok. I don't know why the file was copied over to the local folder. I paid to have my website upgraded with a new theme the last time and suspect they couldn't get something to work so they copied the modified file over to the local folder.

Comment: I don't think there is enough information to give an answer. What modules are you using? What modifications have you made?

Comment: Ok all things are now fixed. See the above for the updates at the end. I hope this will help anyone that has these same issues.

Answer (score 3):

My head hurt while trying to figure this one out.

Just to clarify - I renamed the `image.php` file to `image.php.bak` (located in local `app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Helper`) and this then reverted back to the core file (`app/code/Mage/Catalog/Helper`) this solved the issue. OR like the solution above, copy the file from core and move it to Local.

For me, it seems to be since the new SUPEE-8788 patch has been applied.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This way solved it.. -  renamed the image.php file to image.php.bak (located in local app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Helper) and this then reverted back to the core file (app/code/Mage/Catalog/Helper) this solved the issue. OR like the solution above, copy the file from core and move it to Local.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Finally I found that I badly patched with PATCH_SUPEE-8788 v2 and js/mage/adminhtml/product.js was out of date.

Answer (score 0):

Ihave the same issue. How to uninstall the Catalog Search Refinement extension?