# Image problem in the Admin after 1.9.3 upgrade

Tags: product-images, magento1.9.2.4, magento1.9.3

I upgraded magento from 1.9.2 to 1.9.3 via magento connect, after the upgrade I had a exception during cache cleaning and after a refresh I got a 500 server error.

The hosting company corrected an issue with the permissions on the index.php and my site was live again.

Since then all the product images are missing in the backend but fine on the front end.

Does everyone have an answer? What shall I do?

Re-install modules separately?

Any ideas. Image folder permissions are 777.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [upgraded Magento 1.9.3.0 from 1.9.2.3 admin Images not showing & search broken](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/141040/upgraded-magento-1-9-3-0-from-1-9-2-3-admin-images-not-showing-search-broken)

Answer (score 0):

This is just a browser cache issue. You need to clear your browser cache from the beginning of time and it will resolved the problem. :D